# output all resources or resources of a specific type from terraform workspace

Tags: terraform

0.12 is a little better

I can do this:

```
  value = aws_security_group.abc
```

Instead of just this

```
  value = aws_security_group.abc.id
```

But this is still tedious for workspaces with many imports. I want to output ALL state as a big map I can just import in other workspaces.

I leu of that I would like at least to be able to output all resources of a give type, for example:

```
output "sgs" {
  value = aws_security_group.*
}
```

and then sgs is a map of all the SG resources in the workspace

Comment: You can't do this. There are feature requests for this on GitHub but as far as I know not being worked on.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to this is to write an output expression that refers to all of the resources you want to include, and then the recipients of that value can treat it like a normal map. For example:

```
output "security_groups" {
  value = {
    abc = aws_security_group.abc
    def = aws_security_group.def
    ghi = aws_security_group.ghi
  }
}
```

The expression that creates the value does need to explicitly list them all out, so that it's explicit which keys are in the map and what objects they relate to. But Terraform will resolve all of those references while it's evaluating the output, and so the consuming module will just see it as a normal mapping value and can do generic map-related operations over the elements, like `for` expressions:

```
module "produces_security_groups" {
  # ...
}

locals {
  security_group_ids = {
    for k, v in module.produces_security_groups.security_groups : k => v.id
  }
}
```

Comment: i would be outputting from a workspace not a module does that change anything with this?